# How to import data from file and plot cdf in R

Tags: r

I have two files with one column information. I need to plot cdf of these two column of data in one graph in R.

I used below code but I got a problem.

Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected
Calls: plot -> ecdf -> sort -> sort.default -> [ -> [.data.frame

```
pdf(file = '$filename.pdf', width=5, height=5);
data1 <- read.csv('80211');
data2 <- read.csv('mine');

aCDFcolor <- rgb(1,0,0);
bCDFcolor <- rgb(0,1,0);

plot(ecdf(data1), col=aCDFcolor, main=NA);
plot(ecdf(data2), col=bCDFcolor, add=T);

legend('right', c('data1', 'data2'), fill=c(aCDFcolor, bCDFcolor), border=NA);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below, input for `ecdf` must be numeric.

```
#dummy data
set.seed(123)
data1 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10))
data2 <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10))

aCDFcolor <- rgb(1,0,0)
bCDFcolor <- rgb(0,1,0)

#plot
plot(ecdf(data1[,1]), col=aCDFcolor, main=NA)
plot(ecdf(data2[,1]), col=bCDFcolor, add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: One question. data1 and data2 here have different length. how can I draw them without taking care of this issue. Because when I draw it with plot I can do it but not with ggplot2. I need to get better output with ggplot2.

Comment: ggplot has [stat_ecdf](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_ecdf.html) function for this. Also, there are many posts regarding [ggplot ecdf](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bggplot2%5D+ecdf)